# jQuery draggable div with nested div with style overflow:auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a popup div with a scrolling nested div. I want to be able to mouse down on a scrollbar and scroll down the content. But that action causes the entire div element to drag. Is there any way to resolve this issue? Here is my sample. http://jsfiddle.net/duklee/STF4k/

It seems to be working okay in IE7, not in Chrome & Firefox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked quite a few times.  In an attempt to help keep the future variations of this question down to a minimum, I went ahead and posted a bit more verbose version of the question (and an answer) here: [Disabling jQuery drag when scrolling contents of draggable item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013642/disabling-jquery-drag-when-scrolling-contents-of-draggable-item)

Or you can go directly to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fordlover49/Sr4xb)