# listen for mouse events … except a div's overflow:scroll scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any suggestions for how to listen for mousedown on `$(document)` *except* a div's overflow:scroll scrollbar?

I am not sure what element the scrollbar *is* in order to refer to it...

Comment: in your mousedown handler, look at event.target. that'll tell you what the element is

Comment: Changing `mousedown` to `click` as suggested by @adeneo in [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908292/listen-for-mouse-events-except-a-divs-overflowscroll-scrollbar#comment15854666_11908377) worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the target yourself with :

```
$(document).on('mousedown', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zaLWX/)

The scrollbar is'nt really an element, and click handlers won't work, but it seems mousedown is fired, but will just give you the element the scrollbar belongs to.

To exclude just the scrollbar I'm guessing you will have to figure out it's size, and then check the mouse position on mousedown to see if it's within the scrollbar area.

​

Comment: And how to calculate the scrollbar area?

Comment: That's a little complicated, first you need to create some elements and check the size with and without scrollbars to find the size (it's usually 16px, but you never know), then you'll need to get the mouse position from the event.pageX/Y etc. and finally the elements position, and then figure out if the mouse was pressed in the scollbar area or not. If possible it would be a lot simpler binding to click instead of mousedown, as click does'nt fire on the scrollbar anyway.

Comment: this might prove helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986937/javascript-get-the-browsers-scrollbar-sizes

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='scrollHolder' style='overflow:scroll;'>
<div class='scrollContent'>
</div>
</div>

$(document).on( "mousedown", function( event )
{
    var onScrollbar = false;
    if (event.target.className == "scrollHolder")
    {   
        var s_c = $(event.target).children(".scrollContent");

        if (event.pageX-s_c.offset().left > s_c.innerWidth())
        {
            onScrollbar  = true;
        }
    }
});
```